# Can I load Vue.js from a CDN in production?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cdn

I chose Vue.js for a new project because it seems to run natively in the browser, as opposed to something like React that has to be compiled/transpiled via Node. Is there any reason I couldn't just link to a CDN like this in my production code?

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.1"></script>
```

A co-worker suggested that may be for development only, and that unpkg is simply transpiling on the fly (which doesn't sound good for performance). But other than that it seems to work fine. I could also link to a more robust CDN such as [this one](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/vue), but just want to make sure I'm not violating some sort of best practice by not using a Node build system (e.g. webpack).

Comment: no not really, you might want to use google code, or another more robust cdn. And use the min version if your not already.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/

Comment: Your coworker is wrong on the latter count - unpkg runs the build when the package is published, not when you request it. That said, their [about page](https://unpkg.com/#/about) does suggest you might be better off using a paid CDN in production.

Comment: https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.1 is not minified. You can consider to use a minified version in production environment, either on CDN or saved into your own webapps.

Comment: @JoeClay Realizing the page might have changed in three and a half years, what there made you think unpkg.com wasn't ready for prod? Seems to sell scalability now... "_unpkg is a fast, global content delivery network for everything on npm. Use it to quickly and easily load any file from any package... The origin servers run on world-class auto-scaling infrastructure provided by Google Cloud which dynamically adjusts the number of available servers to meet the current demand for maximum efficiency and uptime._"

Comment: @ruffin: Yeah, the page used to say *"The goal of unpkg is to provide a hassle-free CDN for npm package authors. It's also a great resource for people creating demos and instructional material. However, if you rely on it to serve files that are crucial to your business, you should probably pay for a host with well-supported infrastructure and uptime guarantees."*

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any reason I couldn't just link to a CDN like this in my production code?

No, there is no reason not to use a CDN in production. It's even a preferred way for serving content in production mode, especially with common packages like jQuery, <del>because most of the people would already have loaded and therefore cached this resource</del>.

> A co-worker suggested that may be for development only, and that unpkg is simply transpiling on the fly (which doesn't sound good for performance).

This is absolutely not true - that's why it is a CDN! :) It's a matter of choice, *but* you have to keep in mind that most of the time you should work with **specific version of the library** that you are using during development. If you just add the latest version of any code, you are vulnerable to all changes pushed to that repository, and so your clients will start receiving updated code, which you haven't tested yet.

Therefore fix to a specific version that you develop with, open a beer and have a good sleep :)

**Updated (18.10.2022): Global caching no longer works**

Actually, this one's been around for a while, but the answer was never updated. The short story is that caching works per site. Longer version can be found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/http-cache-partitioning/) (thanks to [@Baraka's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487801/can-i-load-vue-js-from-a-cdn-in-production/42489440?noredirect=1#comment130831640_42489440)).

Either way, using CDN for production deployment **is still much preferred**!

Comment: This is no longer accurate https://developer.chrome.com/blog/http-cache-partitioning/

Comment: Even though caching has changed, the question was mostly about using CDN packages in production, which is still the same. I've updated my answer about caching, thanks for the ping! :)

Comment: Do you have reasoning why using CDN for Prod *is still much preferred* though? It seems very debateable now that caching is per-site.

Comment: They're commonly faster, more reliable, and more secure. Indeed, you can achieve some/all of those by yourself, but it comes with a cost for both infrastructure and humans to execute it :) In terms of public packages - you get them auto-released, easy to manage, and almost certainly faster than your hosting. In terms of functionality (not related here) - you can do wonders with edge functions.

Comment: My previous comment, of course, is in terms of you wanting to use an entire package out of the box (as per the question). If you want parts of it and you're bundling it inside your app - different story :)

Comment: OP is talking about public CDNs which host common packages like vue.js. Bundling vue.js into your application bundle and hosting it either on your own hosting or your own CDN is probably better. If your application js can't be accessed due to server reliability, then there is no benefit to accessing the vue.js bundle on the public CDN. Adding another domain into the mix reduces performance as the additional time for DNS lookup/connection will often outweigh any CDN speed benefit. Even without bundling vue.js in, it still may be better to host it on the same domain as your application js.

Comment: DNS caching is precisely one of the reasons global CDNs are faster than your custom hosting ;) But let's stop here - there are no reasons to discuss why CDNs are good. If they were not, tons of businesses wouldn't exist :)

Comment: We aren't discussing if CDNs are good. We're discussing whether you should use existing public CDNs that host popular libraries. You can host your app and the libraries, either bundled together, or not, on your own CDN.

The browser will always need to lookup your host, as your app will be hosted there. The public CDN may or may not have DNS cached. So there may be less lookups required.

Using public CDNs to include libraries was popular when caching across sites occurred. Since 2020 there is not much benefit from a performance perspective - in fact it's likely a negative.

Comment: We know the benefits of CDNs, being that files are accessed from servers close to the user. Setting up a CDN to do this is easy these days. Your app js and the library js (bundled or not) should ideally be hosted on the same domain to maximise performance. Cross-resource domain caching was the primary reason including from unpkg.com etc was popular. Now they're used more for ease of setup rather than performance. It is definitely less popular to do this than it used to be.

Answer (score 3):

These maybe help:

```
<!-- development version -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<!-- production version -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

And it will keep current version of Vue.js automatically.

Comment: Absolutely **NOT** recommended! What happens if there is a major change and it's not backward compatible? I'll tell you - your code stops working without you knowing it. Never good for the business :)

Comment: You can specify the current version with that url to be safe: https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.min.js